# Why is -(int) int being any int value ,an r-value?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   printf("%d", ++(-i));
   return 0;
}
```

This is obviously an Compilation Error as post(pre)increment/decrement take l-values. So in this case `-i` is r-value BUT how and why?

Comment: Suppose `++(-i)` would compile. What exactly do you propose it should do?

Comment: What else could it possibly be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: -i Wha kind of address is that?

Comment: @CoryKramer: Hardly.

Comment: i copied this code from where i was learning C showing how post(pre)increments(decrements) take only l-values.
So i am confused as to what is -i then
I mean ++i will work fine but why is ++(-i) a prob ?

Comment: What should the compiler do with `++5;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preincrement operator `++` (and other similar operators) requires an lvalue, which is an expression that not only has a type/value but also refers to an object. Roughly speaking, lvalues are things you could put on the left hand side of the `=` operator (but there are some exceptions) or put after the `&` (address-of) operator (but there are some exceptions here too).

The term `rvalue` is slang (not defined by the language standard) for expressions which are not lvalues. In the case of `-i`, `i` is an object, but there is no *object* `-i`; `-i` is just the resulting value from negating the value of `i`. Assigning something to `-i` is not possible because there is no object/storage it refers to.

Comment: I think the term that's used is "value of an expression" (see footnote 64 in C11).

Comment: aaha i get it -i is modified and its not stored anywhere hence making it a r-value , which further effects the ++(post increment ) part of code.Hence compilation error.
DID i get it correct ?

Comment: @AbhinavRana: Basically, yeah.

Comment: *rvalue* isn't slang, it's used in the C++ language standard, and then somewhat abusively used in C discussions

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well it's slang as far as C is concerned. There are lots of terms from C++ that are imprecise or just wrong if used to discuss C, and "slang" seems like a good characterization of such usage.

Comment: @AbhinavRana: Almost. But the same would apply if it were `+i` or `i+0`, which both have the same value as `i` but are not lvalues. The key detail is that these expressions are a result of applying some (possibly trivial, nop-like) operations on `i`, and as such merely have a value but are not "the object `i`".

Answer (score 2):

The unary `-` operator produces a r-value. `++` cannot operate on r-value. Very right.

Now, to answer the "why", let me quote `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.3

> The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand.

The "result" here, is a *computed value*, it is not held by any variable. In other words, as mentioned in the comments, `-i` does not produce any object, so it is not an *lvalue*, it is considered as *r-value*, or *non-lvalue*.